# IBM Worklight: JNDI setting in SQLAdapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have created a data source with JNDI name "jdbc/testingDS" in WAS. (test connection is successful).

I would like the SQL Adapter to connect to that data source so I have updated the adapter XML as below:

```
<connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
    <dataSourceJNDIName>java:comp/env/${custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name}</dataSourceJNDIName>
</connectionPolicy>
```

However, there is error **Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Datasource jdbc/testingDS not found in jndi**. Is there any suggestion on how to set the data source with JNDI name in SQL Adapter? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** 
Here is my setting in worklight.properties:

```
custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name=jdbc/testingDS
custom-db.1.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
custom-db.1.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myipaddress:1521:xe
custom-db.1.username=myusername
custom-db.1.password=mypassword
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Environment: Worklight 5.0.6 Consumer Edition, WebSphere Application Server 8.5

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it will work with "java:comp/env/jdbc/testingDS" instead of "jdbc/testingDS"

Comment: I have tried but it is also not working. Do I need to do the setting in worklight.properties as well?

Comment: What about <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/jdbc/testingDS</dataSourceJNDIName>
 or maybe
<dataSourceJNDIName>java:/testingDS</dataSourceJNDIName>

Comment: Both are not working. Since I am adding the data source in WAS, I am afraid that I have missed other necessary settings in Worklight on calling those data source. Do you have any other suggestions on that as well?

Comment: Maybe missing a jar file somewhere?

Comment: Do u mean I need to add some jar files to WAS as well? or in Worklight?

Comment: I do believe that you need to setup Oracle in WAS:  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_oracle_manually.html

Comment: Yes, I have already setup Oracle data source in WAS and the test connection is successful in WAS. The problem is that seems Worklight cannot look up the JNDI...

Comment: @red23jordan, how about: <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
<dataSourceJNDIName>${custom-db.1.relative-jndi-name}</dataSourceJNDINam
e>
</connectionPolicy>

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your JDBC connector in the server/lib directory?

Comment: Yes, I have put the ojdbc jar under server/lib directory.